# How to access ListView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my code

```
public class OrderAllFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<Order> orders1;
    private ArrayList<String> orders;
    private ListView orderListView;
    public OrderAllFragment() {

        orders1 = new ArrayList<>();
        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){
            Order o = new Order(i, 1+10);
            orders1.add(o);
            orders.add("dummy" + i);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter (getActivity(), orders1);
        orderListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewOrder);
        orderListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orders);
        //setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_order, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

It works fine for string. That is.

```
//ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orders);
//setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

But this line gives Null Pointer exception.

```
 orderListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is XML file.

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewOrder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Games Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can somebody help me on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
orderListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Line causing issue because `orderListView` is `null` .

Reason is `onCreate` method is called before `onCreateView` and calling `findViewById` for accessing View's from `Fragment` layout will return `null` due to Views are not ready to access.

And in current code calling `findViewById` using `getActivity()` means  accessing `View` from `Fragment` container `Activity` instead of `Fragment` layout because `getActivity()` method return *Context of Activity* instead of `Fragment` which is required to access Views from Fragment.

Use `onViewCreated` or  `onCreateView` for accessing Views from Fragment layout.like:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        orderListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewOrder);
        orderListView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. After changes you suggested its working now. But now onListItemClick is not working. Do i need to make any change for that too?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal: Yes right also need to add click listener to `orderListView` ListView using `orderListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `onCreate` method, & use this instead:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_order, container, false);
    OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter (getActivity(), orders1);
    orderListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewOrder);
    orderListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```